# Serial console in Raspberry Pi 3 for testing FONA 808

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm trying to set up a FONA 808 to connect to the internet to a Raspberry Pi 3, but when I run the serial console "sudo screen / dev / serial0 115200" I'm sometimes answered with "OK" and in others the console displays the message as if it were electromagnetic noise, and at other times the console simply crashes Is this normal? How can I solve that?

I am using a Fona 808 Arduino Shield connected to 5V and the TX and RX ports pass through a level logic shifter to convert the logic of 5V of the fona to logic of 3.3V of the raspberry

I am following this tutorial:

https://learn.adafruit.com/fona-tethering-to-raspberry-pi-or-beaglebone-black/setup

Blocked console:

[image: Blocked console]

Electric noise display:

[image: Electric noise display]

Answer (score 0):

Check your /boot/cmdline.txt file.
This is how I solve my pi with the same error.

nano /boot/cmdline.txt or sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt

### copy the script below and paste this in your cmdline.txt

**dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait**

---

make sure "console=ttyAMA0,115200"  is not on the script.

Make sure you have your original script. Test your pi if it reboot correctly. If it doesn't you can change back the cmdline.txt directly on your sd card and paste your original script.

This command should work with the response back

---

sudo screen /dev/serial0 115200

AT

### ok

Answer (score -1):

This should be a comment but I don't have the reputation to comment so...
Couple of things to try that might help.
1) You shouldn't need the level logic shifter. I don't know exactly what FOAN board you are using but they normally have a Vio pin that sets the voltage of the logic. So in this case you just connect the Vio pin to 3.3V on the Raspberry Pi and the RX and TX will be working at 3.3V.
2) Check your wire connections. Might just be a case of a bad connection.
3) I had better luck with `minicom` than `screen` So a command like this should work to connect the bard. `sudo minicom -b 115200 -o -D /dev/ttyS0`

Comment: Yes, I changed the logical level of the device and so I solved the matter